# Trouble binding user control to view model property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

To make it simple, I've made the following user control: 
XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Ex2.testUC"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Ex2"
             x:Name="testuc"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MyText, ElementName=testuc}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

CS.XAML:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Ex2
{
    public partial class testUC : UserControl
    {
        public testUC()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public string MyText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(MyTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MyTextProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MyText", typeof(string), typeof(testUC));
    }
}
```

Now I've inserted him into a view with a simple view model: 
XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Ex2.testWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Ex2"
        xmlns:control="clr-namespace:Ex2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="testWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <control:testUC MyText="{Binding Path=Text}"/>
        <Button Height="100" Click="Button_Click" Content="CLICK HERE"/>
        <Label x:Name="lbl" Height="50"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

XAML.CS:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace Ex2
{
    public partial class testWindow : Window
    {
        private testVMText vm;
        public testWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            vm = new testVMText();
            DataContext = vm;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            lbl.Content = vm.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

View Model:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Ex2
{
    class testVMText : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public testVMText()
        {
            Text = "default";
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

When I click the button, I want the value of Text in the view model to be printed.
My intention was to bind the text box of the user control text to the Text property in the view model. However, when I change the text in the text box and click the button, the string "default" is always being printed. 
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the Mode of the `Binding` to `TwoWay`:

```
<local:testUC MyText="{Binding Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

You could also set the `BindsTwoWayByDefault` property to true when you register the dependency property in your `testUC` class:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyText", typeof(string), typeof(testUC), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata() { BindsTwoWayByDefault = true });
```